# adding vertical space at the beginning of a html page

Tags: html, css, safari

I want to leave some blank space at the beginning of the html page. 
It must be exactly X pixels heigh.

What would be the best way? Note that it must work on safari.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a margin to the body element.

```
body {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Change 10 to whatever you want it to be.

Comment: Depending on the precise effect desired, it might be more consistent across browsers to use padding rather than a margin as vertical margins collapse between block elements.

Answer (score 3):

this should do it.

```
body {
    padding-top:15px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

add something like this:

```
<div style="height: 100px;">&nbsp;</div>
```

change the 100px to however many pixels you need

Comment: just remember adding a margin or padding to the top of the BODY tag will have this offset on every page.

Comment: This is a more general solution because it lets you insert vertical spaces anywhere, not just on the top of the page. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CSS code: `body {margin-top:XXpx}`, where XX is the height you want